# Why doesn't SymPy integrate this function?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have the following:

```
x,x1,x2,t=symbols('x x1 x2 t')
f=t*x1*x2*(x-t)**(-0.5)
integrate(f,t)
```

I can integrate with respect to `x`, `x1` and `x2`, but when I try to integrate with respect to `t` (which is what I want) I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1295, in integrate
    risch=risch, manual=manual)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 486, in doit
    conds=conds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 908, in _eval_integral
    h = meijerint_indefinite(g, x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1612, in meijerint_indefinite
    res = _meijerint_indefinite_1(f.subs(x, x + a), x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1677, in _meijerint_indefinite_1
    r = hyperexpand(r.subs(t, a*x**b), place=place)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/simplify/hyperexpand.py", line 2473, in hyperexpand
    return f.replace(hyper, do_replace).replace(meijerg, do_meijer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 1408, in replace
    rv = bottom_up(self, rec_replace, atoms=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/simplify/simplify.py", line 999, in bottom_up
    rv = F(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 1393, in rec_replace
    new = _value(expr, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 1336, in <lambda>
    _value = lambda expr, result: value(*expr.args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/simplify/hyperexpand.py", line 2470, in do_meijer
    allow_hyper, rewrite=rewrite, place=place)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/simplify/hyperexpand.py", line 2355, in _meijergexpand
    t, 1/z0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/simplify/hyperexpand.py", line 2281, in do_slater
    t, premult, bh, rewrite=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/simplify/hyperexpand.py", line 2038, in _hyperexpand
    ops += devise_plan(func, formula.func, z0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/simplify/hyperexpand.py", line 1615, in devise_plan
    raise ValueError('Non-suitable parameters.')
ValueError: Non-suitable parameters.
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of SymPy's routines struggle to handle floating point numbers, especially in exponents. Use rational numbers whenever possible. More discussion in [common gotchas and pitfalls](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers).

```
>>> x,x1,x2,t=symbols('x x1 x2 t')
>>> f=t*x1*x2*(x-t)**(-Rational('0.5'))
>>> integrate(f,t).simplify()
Piecewise((2*sqrt(x)*x1*x2*(-I*t**2*sqrt((t - x)/x) - I*t*x*sqrt((t - x)/x) + 2*t*x + 2*I*x**2*sqrt((t - x)/x) - 2*x**2)/(3*(t - x)), Abs(t/x) > 1), (2*sqrt(x)*x1*x2*(-t**2*sqrt((-t + x)/x) - t*x*sqrt((-t + x)/x) + 2*t*x + 2*x**2*sqrt((-t + x)/x) - 2*x**2)/(3*(t - x)), True))
```

Not the nicest answer, but it's an answer. If you know that x and t are, say, positive, it might help in simplification to declare it as such from the beginning. There are also two cases depending on `Abs(t/x)` being greater than 1 or not.

Ways to create the rational exponent 1/2:

- `Rational(1, 2)`
- `Rational('0.5')`
- `S(1)/2`
- or just use `sqrt` function, which has the same effect.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try now integrate(f,t,conds='none') the result is the same. Why?