# Sympy evaluates integral sign wrong

Tags: python, sympy

For an integral calculation, Sympy evaluates the same result as me and [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2F%284x%29%20integral%20from%201%2Fsqrt%282%29%20to%201) with a negative sign.

The integral I am evaluating is strictly positive so it can't have a negative value. My first assumption was that either sympy misunderstood the integral limits or I put them in the wrong order, thus giving me the negative result. So I tried

```py
g=x**2
print((sympy.integrate(g, (x, 1/2**.5, 1))).evalf())
```

which is evaluated perfectly.

Here is my full code, including my function.

```py
import sympy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
sympy.init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)
x = sympy.symbols('x')

f=(1-x**2)**(.5)/(4*x)
print((sympy.integrate(f, (x, 1/2**.5, 1))).evalf())

x1=np.linspace(1/2**.5,1,10000)
f1=np.asarray(list(map(lambda a: (1-a**2)**(.5)/(4*a),x1)))

print(sum(f1)*(x1[1]-x1[0])) #my evaluation, close to wolframalpha
plt.plot(x1,f1) #f1 is fully positive.
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I got my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182396/why-doesnt-sympy-integrate-this-function). After replacing all ```.5```s with ```sympy.Rational('0.5')```, it started evaluating it with the correct sign.

Comment: Some routines in sympy will find it problematic to work with inexact float inputs. This is still a bug though so it should be fixed to make it work with floats.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23494

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thank you! Still, it is working much better than I tried it 5 years ago.